# Как отфильтровать таблицу в jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Пытаюсь настроить фильтр на jsp странице для таблицы. Нашел вот такой вариант: https://daruse.ru/prostaya-filtracziya-tabliczyi-na-jquery Но моя таблица заполняется через jstl

```
 <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
    <tr>
        <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
        <td>${employee.firstName}</td>

       ....
</c:forEach>
```

и я не могу добавить `<tr class="table data"` к фильтруемым элементам. Может я вообще неправильно всё делаю, подскажите, каким способом лучше сделать фильтр в моем случае. С js у меня совсем туго. Вот на всякий случай полная таблица`

```
<style type="text/css">
    TABLE {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    TD, TH {
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    TH {
        background: #b0e0e6;
    }
</style>
<tr>
    <th>Фамилия</th>
    <th>Имя</th>
    <th>Отдел</th>
    <th>Должность</th>
    <th>Дата приема</th>
    <th>Окончание адаптации</th>
    <th>Статус</th>
    <th>Беседы</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr class='table-filters'>
    <td>
        <input type="text"/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table data">
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
    <tr>
        <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
        <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
        <td>${employee.department.name}</td>
        <td>${employee.position}</td>
        <td>${employee.employmentDate}</td>
        <td>${employee.endOfAdaptation}</td>
        <td>${employee.status}</td>
        <td>${fn:length(employee.interviews.toArray())}</td>
        <td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='employees/${employee.id}/edit'" value="Редактировать"></td>
        <td><input type="button"  onclick="location.href='employees/${employee.id}'" value="Открыть"></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</tr>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Jsp позволяет встраивать куски кода java при помощи тега `<%%>`. Так что в вашем случае можно воспользоваться обычным `if`.

```xml
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
<%if (request.getAttribute("employee").getFirstName() != null) {%>
    <tr>
        <td>${employee.lastName}</td>
        <td>${employee.firstName}</td>
    </tr>
<%}%>
</c:forEach>
```

Не забывайте закрывать if (`<%}%>`)

Второй вариант - использовать [jstl c:if тег](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm)

Comment: Я знаю что могу использовать теги <%%>, но как это решает мою проблему я не понял, либо вы не поняли моей проблемы.